# about using library tools in cocoa

Tags: cocoa

which library tool(round textured,textured button,etc) shall i use for [image]

displaying boxes at right corner of uploaded image,also please give me the list of different tools shall i use for all those data(multilined text,clear logs,small images at left corner, etc) from uploaded image.
please reply

Answer (score 2):

You mean the buttons? There's no exact match because Mac OS is not Windows. Use standard buttons with standard appearances.

FWIW, the list of available UI widgets is one of the easiest things to learn about Cocoa. Open Interface Builder and look through the Cocoa library palette. The Cocoa equivalent of everything in your image is there (with the exception of the hyperlinked labels - don't use these in Mac OS applications anyway as they're non-standard and quite unattractive).

Posting a complete list of all the controls and their various settings here is an unnecessary waste of effort when all it takes is for you to drag a button onto a window in Interface Builder and start playing with settings (or looking in the documentation at the various NSButton styles).